# Best way to save the SoapEnvelope with SQLite?

Tags: android, ksoap2

I need to save the SoapEnvelope in the Android database and load it from there as well. Saving is not the issue (BLOB as datatype), but I don't know how to serialize the byte[]-array.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the method presented on the following website, which worked just fine: http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/serializing-and-parceling-ksoap2.html